# How to install cabot in linux

Tags: python, github

I have downloaded and unzip the cabot(python tool) in my linux system.But then I don't know how to install it.In the cabot folder there is setup.sh file. But when I put build or install it is not working.So What to do?

Answer (score 0):

.sh is a shell script, you can just execute it.

./setup.sh

Answer (score 0):

It's an ".sh" file right?
Then to run the same what you have to do is :-
1)Open Terminal
2)Change directory to file location
3) run the following command.
        sh setup.sh

Comment: Basically I want to know how to install cabot?i have executed the shell but cabot is not installed...

Comment: Where did you get the setup files from? Maybe there's some documentation on the install process? Share the link with us!

Comment: Try passing arguments as given on that page to the sh script. It might work! Although i barely understand what that page says i still recommend you going through it..

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Cabot doesn't yet have a simple install script, so there isn't really a shell script that you can just run to install it.

https://github.com/arachnys/cabot/issues/132

Here are the recommended install instructions: http://cabotapp.com/qs/quickstart.html